# check hdd for errors and repair

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot-repair, disk-check

My boot in windows is damaged, i've tried several things and every time (even when i'm trying to format with a clean installation of windows 7, repair disc win7 doesn't work either) i try it gets to a black screen only with the mouse arrow. i installed ubuntu 12.04 via usb stick and everything is working fine, apart some bad sectors 22 that ubuntu states - probably the errors are from there. I would like to know if there is any program like chkdsk.exe in windows to search and repair the hdd (i've already tried disc utility but never gets to the end-i wanted more than 10 hours not even the small check and from command prompt aswell)

Comment: Open the disk utility and check the SMART status of the drive.  Edit your question to include the count of reallocated and pending sectors reported there.

Comment: You cannot repair bad sectors. The disk is going bad. Anything that claims to "repair" that, only works around the bad sectors by tagging them as unusable. I'd recommend buying a new hard drive, and getting all your important data off the current drive, before more sectors go bad and you lose important data.

Answer (score -1):

There is a very good tool called testdisk.

With testdisk you can see bad sectors, repair them, repair whole hard disk drives and you can restore whole file systems (data restore).

I have tested the tool and can say that it is very good.